# How can I integrate itable interactive tables and ipywidget in the same html report generated by voila

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

In jupyter-notebook, I have a report with interactive tables generated by itables (PyPI module) and graphs generated by ipywidgets that I would like to edit in html with voila.

Separately it works, how can I put the two parts together in one html page ?

Thanks,
Marc S.

Comment: I'm not following how Voila fits in this? Can you just use nbconvert with the [no-input](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html) flag to produce the HTML you seek? Then you just host the HTML file made separate from Voila?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution, my html page is now fully interactive.

[image: All elements]
[image: B selected]

Comment: And the solution was? What would have answered your posted question?